# Django receives multiple posts from the browser, Does the browser cache POSTs?

Tags: django, google-chrome

During developement it happens like this: if I am working on a piece of code to receive a POST request; Django will serve up an error page because the code is buggy. Then I fix a syntax error, refresh, a different error, fix that, repeat the process say 8 times.

But on the 8th time the code works, and then Django receives and stores 8 Post entries, not just the last one!

A similar behavior happens in production very occasionally. I am not sure if it is the browser caching the POSTs, then sending them all through at the same time or Django?

I have more problems with this issue with working on offline functionality. If a POST fails, I cache it and then resend it when online again. But then sometimes the failed POST, comes back from the dead from another dimension, and gets sent to Django, and so does the the Sync offline POST, so now its duplicated.

I wrote javascript code to disable the submit button once clicked. I also check for duplicate entries (within a 5 seconds window) before saving, but it only works if one manually submits twice in quick succession, not if it auto sends a bunch of POSTs at the same time. These both are "hacks" that don't address the root cause.

Any clue on how to debug or ways to attempt to solve/debug the issue?

It happens on a few of my views, but heres one I am currently trying to fix, `ScrapEntryView` is the view, and it subclasses `BaseFactCreateView`:

```py
from django.views import generic

from .apps import ScrapConfig as AppConfig
from .forms import ScrapEntryForm
from core.gui.apps import SESSION_FEEDBACK
from dist.machine.fact.views import BaseFactCreateView
from utils.time import ttb
from utils.validation import form_validation
from utils.web import HTTP_OK_NO_CONTENT


class BaseFactCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        if form.is_sync_post:
            # If it is a sync post, can't ask the user to correct it, accept it and log to SysEvent table
            from core.base.models import SysEvent

            SysEvent.objects.create(
                name="Sync POST failed",
                note=str(
                    f'Form errors: {form_validation.plain_text_errors(form)}, Request.POST{self.request.POST}'
                ),
            )
            return HTTP_OK_NO_CONTENT
        return super().form_invalid(form)

    def get_feedback(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.get_full_path_info()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
        response = super().form_valid(form)  # will create self.object
        self.request.session[SESSION_FEEDBACK] = self.get_feedback()
        return response


class ScrapEntryView(BaseFactCreateView):
    form_class = ScrapEntryForm
    template_name = f'{AppConfig.name}/entry.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['site_area_id'] = self.kwargs['site_area_id']
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['site_area_id'] = self.kwargs['site_area_id']
        context['page_title'] = "Scrap Entry"
        context[SESSION_FEEDBACK] = self.request.session.pop(SESSION_FEEDBACK, None)
        return context

    def get_feedback(self):
        obj = self.object
        return {
            'type': 'success',
            'heading': "Scrap Entry Saved",
            'body': f"<b>{obj.weight_kg}</b>kg for machine <b>{obj.machine_setup.machine.name}</b><br>due to <b>{obj.scrap_reason.name}</b>",
            'created_dtz': ttb.to_dstr(obj.created_utc, 'DATETIME_FORMAT'),
        }
```

Comment: Most probably the issue is in the view, so please share that so we can help.

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby Thanks, hmmm I was leaning towards some strange browser behaviour, but I posted the view.

Comment: Browsers don't cache POST and on the contrary, it needs the user consent to resend a POST as it can lead to object multiplication.

Comment: Each time after fixing a syntax error, and then refreshing the page (F5), it does ask for my consent to re-POST.

Comment: Is your form method, POST or GET?

Comment: A POST: `<form method="POST" ... >`